# Store any value and a value of a specific range of classes

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class container{
private:
     std::vector<physical_component> physical;
     std::vector<storage_component> storage;
     --some other stuff not relevant--
public:
    --constructors, getters setters, methods to add to the vectors etc--
}
```

Now I am struggeling with making the physical_component and storage_component classes since I dont know a proper datatype to handle this sort of thing.

Physical_component should be able to:

1. Store a set amount of types, and fully retaining a type (something I can cast to is good enough)
2. Should store the objects in a way that makes them individual from the ones passed (and therefore secure from changes to the orignial class)

I remember something like that excisting in c alongside enum but I dont know the name. Also c++ probably has a better way for that.

Storage_component is supposed to:

1. Store any type
2. (optional) remember the original type

I have no idea how to achieve this properly. I saw std::any but it seems to be rather new therefore I dont know if its a good way to go about this. Also I cant make storage_component a template because I cant store it in a vector then

What is the (proper) way to implement these classes?

Comment: If your compiler and library isn't up to date with C++17 (which introduced [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)) then perhaps [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/any.html)? Or perhaps [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (or its [Boost equivalent](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/variant.html)). Or perhaps check your requirements analysis, and make sure the design doesn't need type-erasure like that? Perhaps it can be solved other ways?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why do people use boost:: btw? I am seeing it everywhere? Is it just because it includes all std:: functions or because its actually better/faster? What is going on here?

Also yes thank you. I found a external resource of the std::any implementation that seems to work fine. I dont think ill download boost just for this

Comment: Some of the functionality now in the standard library, or that will come in future versions of the standard library, started out in the Boost library. For example Boost any. If you don't have a compiler new enough for `std::any` then Boost any is a suitable replacement. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is not a single library, it's a *collection* of many libraries. Some which replicates behavior in the standard library (or often the other way around), but it also have much *much* more.

Comment: Also, since Boost is a *collection* of libraries, you can get it all, or you can get just the parts you need. And if you're on a Linux system, then the distribution probably have *many* packages for Boost, so you can pick and choose the ones you want. Furthermore, many libraries are *header only*, which means a library is just a few header files to be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Store a set amount of types, and fully retaining a type

You probably want [`std::variant<Ts...>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) *(or `boost::variant<Ts...>`)*. It stores **one of** `Ts...` at a particular point in time.

---

> Store any type

If all the types share the same interface, use a traditional `virtual` + `std::unique_ptr` polymorphism approach. Otherwise [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) is the right choice here.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! For the storage id like to use any type (includes int, char, etc) so I guess they wont use the same interface. Does std::any automatically create a copy of the classes passed, or is this something I have to manually do? I have the same question about std::variant

Comment: Both `std::variant` and `std::any` are value semantic types - they will copy the currently active type for you.

Comment: @MoustacheSpy: I added some links to the answer, check them out for more information.